# Why is enthalpy the same in an isentropic and in an actual stagnation process?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I'm learning about stagnation, and currently I'm comparing an isentropic and an adiabatic process where the enthalpy stays the same.

The diagram below helps to illustrate my point. I can't see why the losses generated in the non-isentropic process only reduce the pressure and not the enthalpy (temperature).

Shouldn't the enthalpy, and therefore, the temperature, be higher in the isentropic process? Why does is stay the same on both processes?

Thank you!

[image: Enthalpy-Entropy diagram of stagnation state]

Comment: Pressure and volume change so temperature stays constant.

Comment: enthalpy is a combination of pressure and temperature